# How can I programmatically map a specific line/column number in a JS bundle to its source module?

Tags: javascript, webpack

How can I programmatically, using Node/JS, map a specific line/column number in a JS bundle to its source module (using the source map)?

**Update:** I used the package `sourcemap-explorer` to find the location in the original source. (e.g. `$ sourcemap-explorer bundle.js:1:1234` to find the original source for line 1, column 1234 in bundle.js -- given that bundle.js.map exists in the same directory). Thanks to Phil for the suggestion!

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sourcemap-lookup

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: IE11 in this instance, but the question is more general: I would love a command line solution!

Comment: Given it's a runtime error, you won't get anything on the command line

Comment: Thanks, I rephrased the question now. The error itself isn't really relevant -- I just don't know practically how to use the source map to get the source module given a line/column number.

Comment: The question you linked to does unfortunately not answer the question.

Comment: According to the linked post, IE11 _should_ support source maps so you _should_ be able to see the real location of the error

Comment: I'd be happy to re-open but you'll need to show how IE's debugging tools aren't working for you

Comment: This might be what you're looking for ~ https://www.npmjs.com/package/sourcemap-lookup

Comment: Yes, indeed! Thank you. I'll be happy to answer my own question with your suggestion -- I've been searching for something like this quite a while now.

Comment: Software recommendations are not applicable for StackOverflow answers

Comment: Very well. Thanks again for the suggestion, though -- appreciate the help.

Comment: You could edit the link into your question though. I'm sure it will help somebody else and it beats sifting through the comments to find it 